# Javascript: Most efficient way to add image object to class

Tags: javascript, sprite

I´m adding an image object as a property of a class my current method is as below:

```
Arrow = function(src) {
  this.spriteArrow = new Image();
  this.spriteArrow.src = src;
}
```

If I create multiple instances of the arrow class will it load the the same image multiple times? Or should te image be created outside the scope of the arrow class so it's only created once?

Comment: It will load whatever image source you pass in when you create the object

Comment: If the URL is the same, and the server is correctly setting appropriate cache control headers, the browser will find the image in its cache.

Comment: I'm guessing browsers will cache this after the first request. If you use Chrome's developer tools, you can see if it's cached by looking at the size in the network panel. It will say (from cache).

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with doing it this way? Or is some other method preferred?

Comment: Well if it's going to be the same image all the time, you could put it on the prototype.

Comment: While the points about caching are correct, having the image managed in a central spot might make it easier to track the loading time, in case you want to trigger many things to happen as soon as the necessary image is loaded.

Comment: @Katana314 Could you show me an example of how you would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably non-standard, but your question for me in comments demanded its own answer.

The one advantage to keeping the image separate would be that you could manage resource-loading on its own. For instance: (Pseudo-code! Don't copy-paste)

```
var listOfResources = ['Arrow.png', 'character.png'];
foreach resource in listOfResources: {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = resource
  var onloadCalls = [];
  img.onLoad = function: foreach call in onLoadCalls: call();
  function addCall(call) { onLoadCalls.push(call); }
  loadingResources[resource] = {
    img: img,
    onLoad: addCall
  };
}


// anything that wants to wait until Arrow.png is ready calls this:
loadingResources['Arrow.png'].onLoad(function() ...blah...);
```

If this doesn't make much sense to you, it's probably not essential, but may be useful for a large-scale HTML5 game where lots of things are activated as soon as possible, rather than waiting for every resource to load.